# How to override the Render method?

Tags: html, asp.net, web-controls

I'm looking at a control that must output raw HTML and provide rich design-time support.

How to create a custom server control, extend the WebControl class and override the Render method?

Can you provide an example?

regards,
Blanco

Comment: It's a question from a MCP test.  Wondering how you extend a webcontrol class, overider the render method.  An example would be nice.

Comment: You extend a webcontrol class the same way you extend any other class. You override its methods the same way you do any other overridable method. This is why I am asking what your exact problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create a control that extends web control and overrides the `Render` method (though doesn't actually do anything with it.

```
public class TestControl : System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl
{
    protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        base.Render(writer);
    }
}
```

As you can see this is a fairly trivial answer but complete so I suspect that you didn't actually ask the question that you intended to.

Comment: It sounds like you might need to just read up on some of the fundamentals of C#. The above is pretty basic stuff.